# Splitting the data through SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a table "Employee" as shown below

```
Id    Name
1     John
2     Jaffer
3     Syam
4     Aish
5     Gidson
1     Aboo
2     Sindhu
3     Saravanan
```

I want to get two outputs like

```
Id        
1         
2         
3

Id
4
5
```

Which transformation should i use?

Could you Please help on that?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write two queries.

```
SELECT      Id    
FROM        Employee
GROUP BY    Id    
HAVING      COUNT(Id)>1
```

The above query will give you first output

```
SELECT      Id    
FROM        Employee
GROUP BY    Id    
HAVING      COUNT(Id)=1
```

This will give you 2nd output.

Comment: + 1 So basically 2 OLEDB source :)